# Database inserts fail with no transaction error when UPGRADED to Spring 4.3.7 and Hibernate 5.2.9

Tags: spring, hibernate, weblogic

I have a JEE application that does inserts and reads in the oracle and cache databases. The environment uses web logic, spring and hibernate. We use hbm mapping files. Everything worked fine in: Spring v4.2.7 and hibernate 4.3.10final and Web logic 12.1.2 and java 8.
But after upgrading to spring v4.3.7 and hibernate 5.2.9 final and web logic 12.2.1.2, the inserts fail with 'no transaction in progress' exception in hibernate. Somehow the Web logic JTA transaction is not propagated by Spring to Hibernate - it is broken in spring v4.3.7.
I tried few settings in hibernate properties of org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean but did not help.

**Insert exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress**

Your help is highly appreciated.

Below are the details:

**Inserting data in oracle database worked fine in an application that uses these in Java 8 env:**
weblogic v12.1.2,
spring 4.2.7, 
hibernate 4.3.10,
hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.5,
hibernate-validator: 4.1.0,
ojdbc6,
java 8

**I upgraded these and the inserts fail:**
weblogic to 12.2.1.2
spring 4.3.7 
hibernate 5.2.9
hibernate-commons-annotations 5.01.
ojdbc7

**Spring auto wiring details:**

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="writeTxMethods" expression="execution(* xx.transaction.TransactionManagerInterface.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="writeTxAdvice" pointcut-ref="writeTxMethods" order="1" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="writeTxAdvice" transaction-manager="xxTransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="createData" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean abstract="true" id="xxHibernatePropertiesPojo" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="xxTransactionManager" /> -->
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
            <!--  <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_strong_references">${hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_strong_references.size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_soft_references">${hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_soft_references.size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.statement_cache.size">${hibernate.statement_cache.size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.prepare_sql">${hibernate.prepare_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>-->   
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform</prop>       
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="orclDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>xx/Create.hbm.xml</value>    
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Exception stack trace:**

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3450),
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1418),
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1414),
XX.persistence.hibernate.WriteableManager.create(WriteableManager.java:103),
XX.transaction.xxTxManager.create(xxTxManager.java:800),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62),
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157),
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99),
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282),
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179),
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179),
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213),
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy584.create(Unknown Source),
xx.ejb.xxSynchronousSession.create(XXSynchronousSession.java:400),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62),
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149),
com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101),
com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:101),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171),
com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101),
com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:101),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171),
com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101),
org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73),
org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52),
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor288.invoke(Unknown Source),
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171),
com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215),
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy576.create(Unknown Source),
XX.ejb.XXSynchronousSession_ejtj10_ELOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source),
weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33),
XX.ejb.XXSynchronousSession_ejtj10_ELOImpl.create(Unknown Source),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62),
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invokeInContext(LocalSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:75),
org.springframework.ejb.access.AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.invoke(AbstractSlsbInvokerInterceptor.java:189),
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179),
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213),
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy556.create(Unknown Source),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method),
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62),
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43),
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498),
org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180),
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.createInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66),
org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96),
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232),
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85),
org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74),
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59),
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511),
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266),
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126),
org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37),
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131),
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308),
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121),
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251),
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234),
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208),
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160),
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171),
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293),
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212),
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707),
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268),
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286),
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260),
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137),
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350),
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247),
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3679),
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649),
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326),
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197),
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203),
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71),
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433),
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281),
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259),
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691),
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651),
weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270),
weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348),
weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333),
weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54),
weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41),
weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640),
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406),
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it's a faulty JTA transaction configuration in Spring. Why do you use the Spring 2.5 Transaction Handling with XML and AOP configs.

Check out [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/util/spring/config/jta/AbstractJtaTransactionManagerConfiguration.java) to see how you can do it with Java-based config for a JTA env.